# When I target 32-wide warp CUDA architectures, should I use warpSize?

Tags: c++, cuda, exit, abort

This is a follow-up question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36047035/1593077).

Suppose I have a CUDA kernel

```
template<unsigned ThreadsPerWarp>
___global__ foo(bar_t* a, const baz_t* b);
```

and I'm implementing a specialization of it for the case of `ThreadsPerWarp` being 32 (this circumvents the valid criticism of Talonmies' answer to my previous question.)

In the body of this function (or of other `__device__` functions called from it) - should I prefer using the constant value of `ThreadsPerWarp`? Or is it better to use `warpSize`? Or - will it be all the same to the compiler in terms of the PTX it generates?

Comment: Using `ThreadsPerWarp` should be better from an optimization point of view.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Always and with no exceptions? That is, nvcc doesn't have optimizers which "notice" `warpSize` more clearly than they do `32`? After all, talonmies said in the linked-to question that the generated PTX doesn't assume a warp size of 32.

Comment: In [the answer you linked](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36047035/1593077) from @talonmies, he stated "At the same time, using `warpSize` in the code prevents optimization, since formally it is not a compile-time known constant."  I'm pretty much just reiterating that (I agree with it, obviously).  I guess you are now asking for proof that something doesn't exist - harder to do.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: I actually was thinking maybe something like that _does_ exist, otherwise talonmies would not be advocating for `warpSize` that strongly. But you've essentially answered my question with your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, don't use `warpSize`.

It seems that other than potential future-proof'ness (which in practice is questionable), there is no advantages in using it. Instead, you can very well use something like:

```
enum : unsigned { warp_size = 32 };
```